# Old docs-beta meta appears as unknown site in android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Back in the day, when SO Documentation was in its beta phases and had its own meta site, I registered and added it to my sites on the android app. I just noticed it appears as "Unknown Site docs-beta":

> [image]

I'm guessing the same behavior would reproduce with any closed site (such as failed betas), although I can't think of a way to test this theory at the moment.

System details:

- App version: 1.0.89
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Phone model: Nexus 4

P.S.
IMHO, this is a bug report on the android app, not a documentation specific question. If the mods, disagree, please migrate it to MSO.